# Conditionally selecting rows based on order

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table with columns `score` and `timestamp`. I need to select each row that `score` is a new high, when sorted by `timestamp` (bold rows):

| score | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| **6** | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| **7** | 5 |
| **10** | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 |
| 10 | 9 |
| **11** | 10 |

Answer (score 2):

```
select   records
        ,min(Timestamp) as Timestamp
from    (
         select max(Score) over(order by timestamp) as records, Timestamp
         from t
         ) t
group by records
```

| records | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 10 | 6 |
| 11 | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64j7L1VZsVdLYqmcQ2NrvV/1)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following (Supposing that timestamp is unique):

```
Select T.Score, T.Timestamp
From score_tbl T 
Where NOT Exists(Select 1 From score_tbl D Where D.Timestamp < T.Timestamp And D.Score >= T.Score)
Order By T.Timestamp
```

See a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aW42WGRo5iwWcnP9heTYDs/0).